# Phonegap app. Database concerns/quesetions

Tags: cordova

As a web developer having recently become aware of phonegap I've decided to take the long overdue step and create my first iPhone app.

I have an idea and am ready to get started but first have a question relating to databases.

My app is to use a local database which is to store a lot of information supplied by the user and provide stats based on this. Is there anything I should be aware of or any measures I should take before I start to ensure that the data will not be lost anyway.

Also, when I do updates to the app, how can I ensure that the existing data is not overwritten? I would assume that the package I submit to Apple for inclusion in the app store would contain the database framework. I need the data from any previous versions of the app to remain on update.

You read reviews in the app store where an app has lost a users data for seemingly no reason. This is something I cannot allow to happen with this app. If the user were to lose their data by update or any other reason, it would render the app useless to them.

Comment: You asked about iPhone but I will just mention that updates to Android apps do not interfere with the existing SQLite data.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to educate yourself as to where the database will be saved, so that it will persist in the cloud.

To prevent lost data, you'll also need to keep up to date with the changing landscape of iOS, Android, etc., and be ready to change code to suit.

Generally, updates to the iOS app retain the user's data.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to make use of Apple's cloud options, you could use a local database (Phonegap makes this easy) but also write your own code to sync a user's data to a server you host, using ajax, every hour/every day.

Phonegap also gives you the ability to write to the file system....surely that would survive any amount of app shenanigans?